# How to upload the file on Anaplan without initial upload of file through user interface

Tags: rest, file-upload, anaplan-api

I was trying to upload files onto the Anaplan platform using the REST API.So there was a note mentioned on the Anaplan.
To upload a file using the API that file must exist in Anaplan. If the file has not been previously uploaded, you must upload it initially using the Anaplan user interface. You can then carry out subsequent uploads of that file using the API.
So I was looking for any way to upload the file onto the Anaplan without going through the user interface. As the above statement in the Anaplan API page suggested that you need to upload through the user interface first. So is there any other way we can get away from that user interface part or not

[image]

Comment: What have you done already? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

The first upload is what helps you setup import actions within Anaplan. So, as the documentation states it is going to require some UI activity. Here is a community article that discusses a purely API based approach to solve this:

https://community.anaplan.com/t5/Anaplan-Platform/Uploading-file-Via-REST-API-and-Triggering-Imports/td-p/51791

Comment: The community article doesn't answer the question of how to upload a file directly using API and skipping the UI upload step. @Ashwin Krishnamurthy, Can you please share any resources on how to do it using API.

Comment: Hi Mayank, thanks for pointing that out. I’m trying to say that the first step needs to use the UI (cannot be skipped) and subsequent steps can be done programmatically via APIs. The article I’ve shared above does that pretty much.